# Serialization/deserialization between machines which have difference INT size

Tags: c, sockets, serialization, deserialization

I found on this topic some code snips about serialization/deserialization a struct in order to transfer through socket.
[Serialization issues while sending struct over socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565265/serialization-issues-while-sending-struct-over-socket)

```
unsigned char * serialize_int(unsigned char *buffer, int value)
{
    buffer[0] = value >> 24;
    buffer[1] = value >> 16;
    buffer[2] = value >> 8;
    buffer[3] = value;
    return buffer + 4;
}
```

and

```
int deserialize_int(unsigned char *buffer)
{
    int value = 0;

    value |= buffer[0] << 24;
    value |= buffer[1] << 16;
    value |= buffer[2] << 8;
    value |= buffer[3];
    return value;
}
```

How ever I have a concern that if integer has difference size in difference machine (assume 4bytes for sender and 2bytes for receiver). Then the deserialize_int() above will return wrong value.

So it there any solution for this situation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592465/how-should-i-write-a-struct-to-a-file-in-c/29593394#29593394) for a similar question that recommends the usage of `int32_t` instead of integer to make sure all architecutes have the same size. In your case, what should happen when a 2byte int machine receives an int with value 0xABCDE123? The machine will have to either switch to a bigger variable, or lose some of the data.

Comment: @holgac Yes thank you, your answer is understandable and useful.
But beside that, I have another concern: If I can use your method to make sure the variable's size is equal on difference machine, so do I still need serialization/de-serialization? Because I can just send the variable thought socket in the normal way and then the receiver will store the received value to correct-size variable.

Comment: For integer types and unions, you'll still need to handle endianness of the machine. The code you posted is not endian-neutral and will fail in some machines. It's even worse for floating point types, you can make no assumptions about the representation in another machine (if you want to cover many machines), so you can't just send them. Avoid them if possible, represent them in another way if you have to use them.

Comment: Note that when you have a look at protocol headers, they explicitly specify endianness of the integer types (big-endian, usually)